# How to manually trigger Autohotkey hotstrings?

Tags: autohotkey

In my main Autohotkey script I have several hundred hotstrings like these:

::fe::for example
::f::and
::fi::for instance
::fo::fortunate
::foy::fortunately
::glo::global
::gloy::globally
::ha::have
::hv::however

Fairly often it would be convenient to trigger a hotstring manually (e.g. by pressing ALT-9) rather than pressing and end character. Is there a way to do this? I haven't found anything in my Googling, so maybe there isn't. But it would be useful.

I've read the hotstrings options e.g. :*: but this isn't the same - I want normal hotstring operation, but also the option to manually force them to trigger as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Updated:
So what you are in fact looking for is using ALT+9 as an end character. I'm not sure but you can probably not use key-combinations for that (see hotstring doc). I cannot think of a really clever way of doing that right now. You might try something like

```
::fe::
    Transform, CtrlC, Chr, 3 ; comes from ahk input documentation, I never really understood how this is supposed to work but I guess there is a code for alt 9 as well somehow
    input, key, L1 I M ; wait for the next 1 key
    if(key==CtrlC)
        sendraw forExample
return
```

### Old answer:

You have to outsource the hotstring body:

```
::fe::gosub forExample

forExample:
    send for example
return
```

, then you can define a hotkey somewhere:

```
!9::gosub forExample
```

If you want to be cool, use functions instead of subroutines.

Note:

```
::fe::something
```

is just a short form for

```
::fe::
     send something
return
```

Comment: Thanks Blauhim, I appreciate the reply. My comment to user3419297 applies here as well.

Comment: @GrahamJones right! You actually asked for a way to replace the **end character** via hotkey. This doesnt sound easy and is a fairly good question imo. I'll update the question in a sec

Answer (score 2):

```
::fe::for example
::f::and
::fi::for instance
::fo::fortunate
::foy::fortunately
::glo::global
::gloy::globally
::ha::have
::hv::however

!8:: trigger_hotstring("fi")
!9:: trigger_hotstring("ha")

trigger_hotstring(hotstring){
Loop, Read, %A_ScriptFullPath%  
{
    If InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "::"hotstring "::")
    {
         SendInput, % StrSplit(A_LoopReadLine,"::"hotstring "::").2
                break
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I learned something from that code - many thanks. It doesn't do what I'm after, but maybe I wasn't clear enough, in which case I'm sorry. I'm looking for a way to manually trigger any hotstring, as opposed to setting up hotkeys to trigger individual hotstrings. So for example, I set ALT-9 as my 'manual trigger' hotkey, and when I press it, either the hotstring I've just typed will expand to the replacement text, or if the last thing I typed isn't a hotstring, nothing will happen. In other words, it's exactly like typing an end character, only the end character itself doesn't get sent as well.

Comment: If you don't want the ending character to be sent, add the option **`#Hotstring o`** to the autoexecutable section (top of the script). To the [ending characters](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars) you can add (or remove) whatever single character you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you use AutoHotkey v1.1.06+ you can use [#InputLevel](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InputLevel.htm)

```
::fe::for example
::f::and
; and so on

#InputLevel, 1 ; sending space will trigger hotstrings above this line
!F9::Send {space}
```

**Edit:**

I now see you want to omit the end char which needs a bit of extra work

One way would be to duplicate the hotstrings with additional options:

```
::fe::for example
:*O:fe_::for example ; duplicate the hotstrings like so
::f::and
::fi::for instance
::fo::fortunate
; and so on

#InputLevel, 1
!9::Send _
```

Another way would be to remove the endchar

```
::fe::for example
::f::and
::fi::for instance
::fo::fortunate
; and so on

#InputLevel, 1
!9::
Send {space}
Sleep 100 ; give it time to expand the hotstring, experiment with timing
Send {bs} ; now remove trailing space
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use <kbd>TAB</kbd> as a trigger for all my hotstrings. like

```
:*:@pm  ::mail1@protonmail.com  
:*:@G   ::mail2@gmail.com

:*:Btw  ::By the way,{Left}
```

Note that the space that you see here is a tab and not a space.  you can do this instead of doing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to trigger your macro hotstring.
you can even use more than one Tab so you can be sure that you only trigger it when you really intend to.